# WooCommerce: Product added in hook has same variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to automatically add a product to the customers cart once they added a product. It doesn't matter which product they add.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart', 5, 3);
function add_to_cart($cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity) {
    $added_id = 1234;
    
    $found = false;
    
    // Check if product is already in cart
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->id == $added_id )
                $found = true;
        }
        // If product not found, add it
        if ( ! $found )
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $added_id, 1, null, [] );
    } else {
        // If no products in cart, add it            
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $added_id, 1, null, [] );
    }
}
```

However, the product I'm adding has the same variations as the product the customer added. So if they add `T-Shirt Size M`, my product also has variation `Size M` even though it shouldn't have any variations set at all. I can't seem to figure out what the problem here is any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you change the value of `$added_id` to some other product's id. Do you still face this issue then?

Comment: Doesn't matter even if I add another product which has their own variations (like another T-Shirt) it still takes the same variations from the first product added.

Comment: So if the user were to choose L then the automatically added product also chooses L variation?

Comment: Product chooses "T-Shirt, Size: L", I want to add product "Free gift". Free gift product doesn't have any variations it's just a small gift, but upon adding it the "Free gift" has variation "Size: L".